Doctrine lazy loading returns all relations with null value
I am blocked with a lazy loading issue that appeared suddenly with doctrine, maybe after I have cleaned my vendor and cache folders and did run composer install.
In my symfony app, I have 3 Entities related: User, UserProfile and Address.
User entity
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['email'], message: 'There is already an account identified by this email')]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface, TwoFactorInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'uuid', unique: true)]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: 'doctrine.uuid_generator')]
    #[Groups([GRP_USER_READ, SerializationGroups::REST_R, SerializationGroups::LICENCE_R])]
    private $uuid;

    #[Groups([GRP_USER_READ, SerializationGroups::REST_R, SerializationGroups::LICENCE_R])]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 180, unique: true)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Email]
    private $email;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[Groups([SerializationGroups::REST_R, SerializationGroups::LICENCE_R])]
    private ?UserProfile $profile = null;

...

The UserProfile Entity:
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserProfileRepository::class)]
class UserProfile extends BaseEntity
{
    #[Groups([SerializationGroups::REST_R, SerializationGroups::LICENCE_R])]
    #[ORM\Column(length: 50)]
    private ?string $firstName = null;

    #[Groups([SerializationGroups::REST_R, SerializationGroups::LICENCE_R])]
    #[ORM\Column(length: 50)]
    private ?string $lastName = null;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[Groups(SerializationGroups::REST_R)]
    private ?Address $deliveryAddress = null;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[Groups(SerializationGroups::REST_R)]
    private ?Address $billingAddress = null;

...

And the Address Entity:
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: AddressRepository::class)]
class Address extends BaseEntity
{
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $text = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 80, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $contactEmail = null;

    #[Groups(SerializationGroups::REST_R)]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Country::class)]
    private ?Country $country = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?bool $isMain = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?bool $isDelivery = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?bool $isBilling = null;

    #[Groups(SerializationGroups::REST_R)]
    #[ORM\Column(length: 10, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $postCode = null;

...

That said, when I try to get any attribute of the object like this:
$currentUser->getProfile()->getBillingAddress()

It always returns null.
After running a debug session, I see that $currentUser->getProfile() returns an object of type \Proxies_CG_\App\Entity\UserProfile, which is the normal doctrine behavior.
And now for each relation I have to fetch it using a repository meaning that the direct queries are still working.
I tried the following:

run bin/console cache:clear
remove the cache and vendor folders and rerun composer install
update doctrine schema but no difference has been detected
checked if the database returned the relations correctly using subqueries

What can be done to resynchronize doctrine with the database?
My environment:

php 8.2
symfony 6.2
doctrine/orm 2.20.0
mysql 8.0
docker

UPDATE (21.11.24)
Based on the following configuration I had
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '13'
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                JSON_EXTRACT: Scienta\DoctrineJsonFunctions\Query\AST\Functions\Mysql\JsonExtract
                JSON_SEARCH: Scienta\DoctrineJsonFunctions\Query\AST\Functions\Mysql\JsonSearch
                JSON_CONTAINS: Scienta\DoctrineJsonFunctions\Query\AST\Functions\Mysql\JsonContains
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
        enable_lazy_ghost_objects: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
            gedmo_translatable:
                type: attribute
                prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/src/Translatable/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTranslatable # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false


I had to set enable_lazy_ghost_objects to false and it's working.
According to the symfony doc, this flag "Enables the new implementation of proxies based on lazy ghosts instead of using the legacy implementation".
I decided to enable it for performance, it used to work actually. Now I'm wondering what would be the right config to optimize performance a bit according to lefacy implementation.
